# jQuery Replace with JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
$('input.next_page_img').replaceWith('<input type="submit" class="next_page_image graybutton mediumbutton" alt="Next Page" value="Next Page" title="Next Page" onclick="Add_Search_Param('page', 2); Refine();">');
```

The problem is with the `onclick` function. It makes the rest of the script fail. When I take out the `onclick` function, it works. What do I need to do to fix this?

Scratch that, I've ultimately decided this was a bad idea. Instead I'd rather set the attributes of the inputs... why isn't this working though http://jsfiddle.net/qSBHH/ ?

Comment: You have a quotation mark problem. I suggest to create the element and to attach the event handler with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bookmarker = $('<span />').insertBefore('.next_page_img');
$('.next_page_img').detach().attr({type: 'submit', value: 'save'}).insertAfter(bookmarker);
```

Comment: I've ultimately decided this was a bad idea. Instead I'd rather set the attributes of the inputs... why isn't this working though http://jsfiddle.net/qSBHH/ ?

Comment: I understand... I tried to implement it into my site, it resulted in two save buttons. But also, I reviewed the script and decided it was too "hack"-y for my taste. I replace the src attribute with an all text image and style the button, it came exactly how I wanted it to other than I wanted it to be text. Thank you though. Your first solution answered my initial question so I'll select your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery anyway, it'd be a lot less messy to add the event handler with the library:

```
$('input.next_page_img')
  .replaceWith($('<input type="submit"/>', {
    'class': "next_page_image graybutton mediumbutton",
    'alt': "Next Page",
    'value': "Next Page",
    'title': "Next Page",
    'click': function() {
      Add_Search_Param('page', 2);
      Refine();
    }
  }));
```

You can jam all that on one line if you like.

Comment: I've ultimately decided this was a bad idea. Instead I'd rather set the attributes of the inputs... why isn't this working though http://jsfiddle.net/qSBHH/ ?

Comment: What exactly makes it a "bad idea"?  It's much easier to maintain; having to quote raw JavaScript code with strings in is pretty ugly. *edit* oh wait -- you mean that what you were doing in the first place was a bad idea?  Sorry I'm confused now :-)

Comment: @Pointy, how can "click" work there. It should be same as `$(elem).attr("click", function(){})` which doesn't make any sense. Am I doin' it wrong?

Comment: My whole entire idea was bad, since the onclick event changes every next page you go to...

Comment: @Esailija Note that I wrapped the `<input>` in its own jQuery call. When you're calling jQuery to create a node, you can pass a second object argument with attributes to set. The library knows to look for the handler names there. It also recognizes "css" and checks if its value is an object.

Comment: @Pointy lol you are right, the special attr hooks and attrFn's are all over the source code and I had some trouble finding them :P (Note to self: Maybe I should read the docs, instead of source code?)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do this:

```
$('input.next_page_img').replaceWith($("<input>", {
    type: "submit",
   "class": "next_page_image graybutton mediumbutton",
    alt: "Next Page",
    value: "Next Page",
    title: "Next Page"
}).bind("click", function() {
    Add_Search_Param('page', 2);
    Refine();
}));
```

Comment: I've ultimately decided this was a bad idea. Instead I'd rather set the attributes of the inputs... why isn't this working though http://jsfiddle.net/qSBHH/ ?